# Пунктуация и использование запятых при уточнении информации о товаре

Tags: пунктуация

Продукция: Самсунг холодильник-морозильник модель B429 2 ед/компл артикул 00513444. Нужны ли запятые где-то в предложении выше?

Answer (score 1):

*Продукция: **Самсунг, холодильник-морозильник модель B429, 2 ед/компл, артикул 00513444.***

Запятые ставятся при перечислении технических характеристик.

Comment: Может, "модели" всё-таки лучше?

Comment: Это технический текст, может, у них принята такая запись (для точности).  Как вариант, можно поставить  запятую.

Comment: Согласен) *****